# Cartesian product on multiple array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, cartesian-product

I have been working on cartesian product for single elements and array of objects. For single array elements I have understood the solution but for array of objects I struggle to achieve.
For example input

```
cartesianProductOf([{col1:'A'}], [{col2:'B'},{col3:'C'}])
```

Output :

```
[{col1:'A',col2:'B'},{col1:'A',col3:'C'}]
```

Here is the function which I was working on

```
function cartesianProductOf() {
     return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {

         var ret = [];
         debugger;

         a.forEach(function(a) {
                 b.forEach(function(b) {
                 var r = a.concat([b])
                 ret.push(r);
             });
         });

         return ret;

    }, [[]]);
}
```

This function returning this result

```
[{col1:'A'},{col2:'B'}],[{col1:'A'},{col3:'C'}]
```

Need guidance.

Comment: is there a reason you need to use reduce?

Comment: I believe the true Cartesian Product here is actually `{{col1:'A'},{col2:'B'}},{{col1:'A'},{col3:'C'}}`.  However, that is not a valid javascript construct as a javascript object must be a name-value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an array to push to, you want to merge the objects:

```
function cartesianProductOf() {
     return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) {
         var ret = [];
         a.forEach(function(a_el) {
             b.forEach(function(b_el) {
                 ret.push(Object.assign({}, a_el, b_el));
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             });
         });
         return ret;
    }, [{}]);
//      ^^
}
```

If you don't want to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or it's polyfill, the equivalent would be

```
                 var r = {};
                 for (var p in a_el)
                     r[p] = a_el[p];
                 for (var p in b_el)
                     r[p] = b_el[p];
                 ret.push(r);
```

Answer (score -2):

## Here's a solution using Ramda.js

```js
const cartesianProduct = (...Xs) =>
  R.reduce(
    (Ys, X) =>
      R.map(R.apply(R.append), R.xprod(X, Ys)), 
    [[]],
    Xs
  )

const cartesianProductOf = (...objs) =>
  R.map(R.mergeAll, cartesianProduct(...objs))

console.log(
  cartesianProductOf(
    [{col1: 'A'}],[{col2: 'B'}, {col3: 'C'}],
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```